# EF Core scaffold dbcontext doesn't generate StringLength attribute

Tags: entity-framework-core

I am using Scaffold-DBContext commnand in order to create a model from my database.
I use the option -DataAnnotations for generating DataAnnotation attributes.
I got Required and ColumnAttribute, for example:

```
[Required]
[Column(TypeName = "varchar(100)")]
public string Cognome { get; set; }
```

But I don't have StringLength attribute.
Is there any way to generate this attribute?
Thank you.

Comment: I think this is changing in version 2.0.0. You'll get `[StringLength(100)]`, no `[Column]`, and `.IsUnicode(false)` instead.

Comment: I tried it with Microsoft.EntityframeworkCore version 2.0.0-preview1-final but I stil don't have StringLength attribute

Comment: 2.0.0-preview2-final will be the first release to do it. You can use the [nightly builds](https://dotnet.myget.org/gallery/aspnetcore-dev) if you're interested in trying it out.